# Selecting an option in the mobile app drop down which is not visible when the app is loaded for the first time

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, automation, appium

I need to select the top most option in this drop down (Image attached) (This is an android app which Im automating using C# and Appium)

[image: dropdown options]

I tried various ScrollTo methods but nothing worked so far. At least if it can select the value that I pass event without scrolling, thats fine